# How to access the data from QLineEdit?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using PyQt5 to develop an application. For the current window, I'm using **init**() function and a MainUI() function to keep the UI separate. And then I just used self.MainUI() in the init function. Now I want to access the data that an user enters in a QLineEdit. How do I go about that?

```
class CreateDBWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('mood tracker')
        self.setFixedWidth(1080)
        self.setFixedHeight(720)
        self.MainUI()
        self.show()

    def createDatabase(self):
        print(self.host.text())

    def MainUI(self):
        host = QLineEdit(self)
        host.move(190,150)
        host.setFixedWidth(500)
        host.setFixedHeight(40)
        host.setStyleSheet('font-size: 20px')
        host.show()
```

But when I run this code, it gives this error - AttributeError: 'CreateDBWindow' object has no attribute 'host'

Comment: `self.host = QLineEdit(self)` etc. Please do some studying about classes, instances, attributes and the purpose of `self` in Python. Also, learn to use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: @musicamante I think this question warrants a proper answer. It's not so much a typo, rather a misunderstanding about how Python class member variables work. Just because solution is simple, doesn't mean it's easy figure out for a Python novice without help.

Answer (score 1):

You would get the text of QLineEdit using signals.

https://zetcode.com has good tutorials for PyQt. Here is the [QLineEdit Example](https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/widgets2/) from there showing how to use signals:

```
class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.lbl = QLabel(self)
        qle = QLineEdit(self)

        qle.move(60, 100)
        self.lbl.move(60, 40)
 
        # connect textChanged signal to self.onChanged slot
        qle.textChanged[str].connect(self.onChanged)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('QLineEdit')
        self.show()

    def onChanged(self, text):
        self.lbl.setText(text)
        self.lbl.adjustSize()
```

So your example would be like this:

```py
class CreateDBWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('mood tracker')
        self.setFixedWidth(1080)
        self.setFixedHeight(720)
        self.MainUI()
        self.show()


    def onChanged(self, text):
        print(text)

    def MainUI(self):
        self.host = QLineEdit(self)
        self.host.move(190,150)
        self.host.setFixedWidth(500)
        self.host.setFixedHeight(40)
        self.host.setStyleSheet('font-size: 20px')
        self.host.textChanged[str].connect(self.onChanged)
        self.host.show()
```